# What are some good User Interface words/phrases

Tags: website-design

I'm a programmer, and I come across the issue of naming UI elements on web pages often.

What are some good words/phrases?

Like:

- Dialog popup
- Modal Window
- Alert Box
- Image carousel

Is there a list of standardized UI metaphors somewhere?

Comment: Are you asking about "good for user" or "good for developers"? Your example point towards the latter.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: Terms like 'modal dialog' are likely to be understood by programmers, but will rarely be understood by the average user.

Comment: as Bobby Jack said. A *typical* user does not know (or correctly interpret/use) terms like "popup" or "modal". They have a very precise meaning for techies, but for users, the meaning is vague at best. --- that means: use less, simpler, more common terms when communicating with users.

Comment: you mean to say that between the designers and the users there is a vocabulary gap. something that the designers need to acknowledge and work to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ui-patterns.com/
http://www.patternry.com/
http://quince.infragistics.com/#/Main

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great glossary for Web Design as a whole with lot of expressions you should know:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/webdesignhtmlatoz/a/blglossary.htm